What happens when the Viterbi trellis is full?
When the Viterbi trellis traceback is completely filled, but more encoded data needs to be processed, what happens?

Is the oldest states in the trellis removed, with their decoded bit(s) extracted and associated with the second-oldest connected nodes?

Is the best path metric selected and the trellis reset with the new starting node at the state of the selected path?

Something else?


